# Dynamically added checkbox not selectable - Material Design Lite (MDL)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, material-design-lite

Here is my simple example.

This little app creates 20 checkboxes with jQuery, using `#checkbox-template` as a template. The `for` attribute of the label and the `id` of each input are altered to be unique.

- Expected behavior: Each checkbox should be selectable. Actual
- behavior: Checkboxes are not selectable.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My Example</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- TEMPLATE -->
  <templates style="display: none">

    <div id="checkbox-template">
      <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="podcast-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="podcast-checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
        </label>
    </div>

  </templates>

  <!-- List -->
  <div id="my-list"></div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var newItem = $("<div>");
        newItem.html($("#checkbox-template").html());
        newItem.find("#podcast-checkbox-container").attr("for", "the-item-" + i);
        newItem.find("#podcast-checkbox").attr("id", "the-item-" + i);

        componentHandler.upgradeElement(newItem.get(0));
        newItem.appendTo("#my-list");
      }

    });
  </script>


  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every labels **for** attribute is mapped to nested checkboxes **id**.
After setting up this, you can upgrade all elements using `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();` in one go.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My Example</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">

</head>

<body>

<!-- TEMPLATE -->
  <templates style="display: none">

    <div id="checkbox-template">
      <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="podcast-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="podcast-checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
        </label>
    </div>

  </templates>

  <!-- List -->
  <div id="my-list"></div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var newItem = $("<div>");
        newItem.html($("#checkbox-template").html());
        newItem.find("#podcast-checkbox-container").attr("for", "the-item-" + i);
        newItem.find("#podcast-checkbox").attr("id", "the-item-" + i);
        newItem.find("label").attr("for", "the-item-" + i);

        newItem.appendTo("#my-list");
      }
      componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. :( Also, if you click the "Run code snippet" on Stack Overflow, you could confirm it doesn't work.

Comment: Here is a gif i tested on chrome [https://imgur.com/a/KDoQ8j6](https://imgur.com/a/KDoQ8j6)

Comment: Works with the window on load! Do you think there's any way to get this working after the window loads so I could add these checkboxes more dynamically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193418/discussion-between-priyesh-diukar-and-doug-beney).

Comment: @Dough Beney. It does work after window load. It is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My Example</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- TEMPLATE -->
  <templates style="display: none">

    <div id="checkbox-template">
      <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="podcast-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="podcast-checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
        </label>
    </div>

  </templates>

  <!-- List -->
  <div id="my-list"></div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var newItem = $(`<div id="checkbox-template"><label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="podcast-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="podcast-checkbox the-item-${i}" class="mdl-checkbox__input" /></label></div>`);

        newItem.appendTo("#my-list");
      }

    });
  </script>


  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: newItem is a div container that contains the label and checkbox. Checkout the line that begins with "newItem.html".

Comment: ok i see, check out the edited answer please, hopefully that is the answer you are looking for.